# How to manage permissions for Azure Devops Extensions

Tags: azure-devops

In my org, I have a bunch of custom made extensions, one of which I would like to only allow access for specific users. Note that I only want this specific extension to be restricted, while other extensions must be accessible to all users in the org.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Define restricted. May others see them, but not actually run them? Must admins see them always? 
And it sound a bit ugly to me, but one could verify the user id (calling some devops apis) from within an extension's task script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want specific members of your organization to not see a specific extension, this is not possible. Azure Devops and the extension management portal have not yet provided such permissions. You could submit your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions.

If you want to restrict user access outside your organization,you can do it through the following steps. When your extension is public, you should first change the `public` property to `false` in the `vss-extension.json` file to make your extension is private.

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "my-first-extension",
    "publisher": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "description": "A sample Visual Studio Services extension",
    "public": false,
    "categories": ["Azure Repos"],
    ...
}
```

The `public` property controls whether the extension is visible to everyone on the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Then from the [management portal](https://aka.ms/vsmarketplace-manage), select the extension from the list, right-click, and choose `Share/Unshare`.

Select the `+ Organization` button, enter the name of your organization, and press enter.You can add users who are allowed to access this extension to this organization.Because your extension is private, only you (as the publisher of the extension) and any member of the organization it is shared with can see the install page. For details,please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops#install-your-extension).

Comment: I needed a solution for members within my Org, but set this as the answer because of it answers my question (that there is no such feature at the moment). Thanks!